# HtmlUnit clicking on a HtmlAnchor

Tags: html, click, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit version 2.43.0 with maven.

After successfully logging into a site with a username/password and a HtmlSubmitInput click, the next HtmlAnchor button has stumped me. I'm not sure what to do.

The button looks like the following:

`<a class="DirectoryEntries_LoadMoreEntriesButton vx-button" onclick="$(this).text('Loading...')" data-remote="true" href="[redacted]/directory_entries/2">Load More</a>`

My current code is:

```
htmlPage = ((HtmlAnchor) htmlPage.getFirstByXPath("//a[contains(@class, 'DirectoryEntries_LoadMoreEntriesButton vx-button')]")).click();
String page = htmlPage.asXml();
```

However, the page is the exact same as before apart from the "Load More" being replaced with "Loading..." It stays like this forever, even after multiple `Thread.sleep()` and `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript()`  calls.

On the site itself, when you click the Load More button, it gets replaced with more directories. Originally there are 50, but 15 more get added.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by switching to Selenium (v3.141.59) and pretty much doing the same thing. I guess the JS support on HtmlUnit is not the best.